# Mockito Stubbing callbacks

Tags: callback, mockito, stubbing

I am new to Mockito.  I am using mockito 1.9.5. and junit 4 that comes with eclipse kepler.
When I ran this test in my junit below.

```
<pre><code>
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    public void stubbingCallbacks(){        
        when(mockedList.add(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                //Object mock = invocation.getMock();
                return "called with arguments: " + args;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(mockedList.add("a"));
    }
</code></pre>
```

Then it throws me this exception

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at $java.util.LinkedList$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2744633c.add()
        at com.mock.Verifying.stubbingCallbacks(Verifying.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Does anyone know why is it throwing ClassCastException?  And 
How do I solve this problem?

Thank you so much for your help

Sura

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course : `List.add(item)` returns a `boolean` and your answer returns a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to violate the return type of the method you are mocking. The return value of `mockedList.add()` is boolean so your mock should also be boolean other than `"called with arguments: " + args`